# WebView Windows 8.1 TextField

Tags: c#, html, webview, windows-phone-8.1

I am using Webview to displays an html page that contains 2 inputs of type text and a submit button.I want the app user to be able to fill these fields on the app before launching the webview.Therefore taking the user directly to the result of the search.
Apparently the webview.Document is no longer available.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

Once the HTML is loaded into WebView, you can call a method called InvokeScriptAsync through which you can invoke some kind of Javascript.

```
await myWebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "var elem = document.forms[0].submit();"});
```

This way you can fill the input field, click a button or whatever you need.

Comment: What should eval be? and where should the textfield name be? Thanks